# issue with cs5.5: Can't install ipa on ios version prior to 4.3.1

Tags: iphone, flash, ios, flash-cs5, ipa

Just downloaded cs5.5 and published my game for ios. The generated ipa file can install on iphone with ios4.3.1, but when I tried to install it on devices with ios4.2.1 or ios3.1.2, I got message like "xxx was not installed on the ipod because it is not compatible with this ipod".

I haven't had this problem before I upgraded from cs5... need help... will be waiting for the answer online~~

Comment: same problem here...need help! Can anyone tell us how to solve this?

Comment: don't know about ipod...but it definitely works on the iPad with software versions 4.2.X and 4.3.X

Answer (score 0):

I have had the exact same problem as you and I think I figured it out. It turns out that Adobe Flash CS5.5's iOS package is optimized for iOS 4.2.1 and later (if I am not mistaken of course). Luckily, Flash CS5's iOS package works with pretty much any iOS version.

I own an iPhone 3G and I found out the hard way when it came to compiling my project.

I hope this helps you. Who knows? Maybe Adobe will release an update soon to fix this issue!